# Determining if a branch cut is valid

Tags: complex-analysis

So I have the function
$$f(z)=(z^2-1)^{1/3}(z-i)^{1/3}=(r_1r_2r_3)^{1/3}\exp[\frac i3(\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3)]$$

And I want to know if the branch cuts at x from -1 to 1 and along y from i to infinity make this single values.

In order to test, do I want to check what happens when $\theta_i\rightarrow\theta_1+2\pi$?  in this case, then the phase will remain the same?  However this is not specific to the branch cut.  So I am confused how to approach this.

EDIT::
[image]

Comment: $\infty$ is not a branch point of $f$, so cutting from $i$ to $\infty$ helps nothing. The cut must connect all three branch points.

Comment: Alright.  So if I had cuts from -1 to infinity, 1 to infinity and i to infinity, then that also would not work because they are not connected?

Comment: Then they would be connected. "Connected" refers to the Riemann sphere here, and there the cuts connect at $\infty$.

Comment: Hmmmm.  So how could I tell if any arbitrary cut is valid?

Comment: So say I had 2 cuts connecting (-1,0) with (0,i) and (1,0) with (0,i).  Would that result in a single valued function

Comment: Yes, cutting from $-1$ via $i$ to $1$ gives you a domain on which there is a branch. If your cut doesn't self-intersect, the complement with respect to the sphere is simply connected, and on simply connected domains not containing branch points, you can always choose local branches that fit together globally.

Comment: So how could I show that those sets of cuts gives a single value function?  I have tried looking at the phases on the argand diagram for i+$\delta$ and i-$\delta$ as \delta goes to 0.  I get completely different phases, implying that f(z) is multivalued

Comment: Are you using a CAS to compute it/draw a picture? These things tend to be stupid with regard to branch cuts, unless you know exactly how to use them, possibly. By default, if you let them compute $a(z)^{1/3}\cdot b(z)^{1/3}$, you get some standard result for the cube root of $a(z)$ multiplied with the standard cube root of $b(z)$. Well, they usually don't know where you want your branch cuts, so it's excusable. If you take a branch cut consisting of two straight line segments connecting $-1$ and $i$ resp. $i$ and $1$, or the upper half of the unit circle, or something similar, then (cont.)

Comment: note that on $G = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z\rvert > 1\}$ you can write (one branch of) the function as $$f(z) = z\cdot \sqrt[3]{1 - \frac{1}{z^2}}\cdot \sqrt[3]{1 - \frac{i}{z}},$$ where the two cube roots are the principal branch of $\sqrt[3]{1-w}$ on the unit disk. The other two branches of $f$ are obtained by multiplying with a third root of unity. Thus on $G$ it's easy to see that you have a well-defined holomorphic branch of $f$. Then you can extend that to the remaining part of the complement of the branch cut by analytic continuation.

Comment: I am just doing it by hand, no CAS.  I will try to upload what I mean.

Comment: I have uploaded what I am doing.  I have defined (z-1) as r1 e^i$\theta_1$ and so on

Comment: I can't really decipher what you sketched there. It looks like you're approaching the branch cut from different sides. You get different values when you approach a point on the cut that is not a branch point from different sides of the cut. If you got the same value from both sides of the cut, you'd get a continuous extension, and by Morera actually a holomorphic extension - that would mean your cut is not really a branch cut. At the branch points, the limiting value is the same ($0$) from both sides, but the argument of $f(z)$ jumps when the direction from which you approach the branch point

Comment: crosses the cut. That's how things are. Perhaps you are confused by the fact that you can't globally define the $\theta_i$ on the complement of the cut?

Comment: Sorry that I am really confused.  We only covered branch cuts and not any kind of analytic extension.  Where I think I am confused is what is referred to as crossing the branch.  When I defined the angles, they were with respect to the drawn axis.  Do I have to limit this?  For example I have theta2 as pi/4 for both, however doesn't this imply that i crossed the cut?

Comment: So as I go along what I have drawn as C, I am trying to find the angles as drawn.  Not sure what you mean by globally defining these angles on the complement of the cut?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a power function $f$ using
$$
          f(z) = f(z_0)\exp\left(\frac{1}{3}\int_{z_0}^{z} \frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z+1}+\frac{1}{z+i}dz\right),
$$
where the path from $z_0$ to $z$ lies in some connected region for which every closed path integral has a value equal to an integer multiple of $6\pi i$. This assumption will make sure that $f$ does not depend on the path from $z_0$ to $z$.

A region that is obtained by removing the segment from $-1$ to $1$ and the ray from $i$ to $i\infty$ is not a valid region because you can integrate around $z=\pm 1$, and you'll get $4\pi i/3$ in the exponent, which means you end up with a discontinuous definition. However, if you remove the directed polygonal path joining $-1$ to $1$ to $i$, then you're okay because the sum of all three residues is $6\pi i$ and $6\pi i/3$ is a multiple of $2\pi i$.